# SXA Federation Authentication via Identity Server

Tags: identity-server, federated-authentication, sso

I am working on federation authentication via the Identity server in Sitecore 10.2 SXA. Created below class

```
  public class DemoIdentityProvider : IdentityProvidersProcessor
    {

        private readonly ICookieManager cookieManager;
        readonly string clientId = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("ClientId");
        readonly string redirectUri = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("RedirectUri");
        readonly string clientSecret = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("ClientSecret");
        readonly string authority = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("Authority");
        readonly string postLogoutRedirectUri = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("PostLogoutRedirectUri");
        readonly string errorUri = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("ErrorMessage");
        public DemoIdentityProvider(
            FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration federatedAuthenticationConfiguration,
            ICookieManager cookieManager,
            BaseSettings settings) : base(federatedAuthenticationConfiguration, cookieManager, settings)
        {
            this.cookieManager = cookieManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cookieManager));
        }

        protected override void ProcessCore(IdentityProvidersArgs args)
        {
            var authenticationType = this.GetAuthenticationType();
            var identityProvider = this.GetIdentityProvider();
            var saveSigninToken = identityProvider.TriggerExternalSignOut;

            var oidcOptions = this.SetupOidcOptions(authenticationType, saveSigninToken);

            args.App.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(oidcOptions);
        }

        public OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions SetupOidcOptions(
            string authenticationType,
            bool saveSigninToken)
        {
            var oidcOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = authenticationType,
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
                Authority = authority,
                ClientId = clientId,
                ClientSecret = clientSecret,
                ResponseMode = OpenIdConnectResponseMode.FormPost,
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdTokenToken,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                RedeemCode = true,
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile + " " + OpenIdConnectScope.OfflineAccess,
                RequireHttpsMetadata = true,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                   // RedirectToIdentityProvider = this.RedirectToIdentityProviderAsync,
                    SecurityTokenValidated = this.SecurityTokenValidatedAsync
                },
                TokenValidationParameters =
            {
                SaveSigninToken = saveSigninToken
            },
                CookieManager = cookieManager
            };

            return oidcOptions;
        }

        protected override string IdentityProviderName => "DemoIdentityProvider";

        protected BaseLog Log { get; }

        public Collection<string> Scopes { get; } = new Collection<string>();

        private Task SecurityTokenValidatedAsync(SecurityTokenValidatedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
        {
            var identityProvider = this.GetIdentityProvider();
            var identity = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

            foreach (var current in identityProvider.Transformations)
            {
                current.Transform(identity, new TransformationContext(this.FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, identityProvider));
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Patch file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
    <sitecore>
        <federatedAuthentication type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
            <identityProvidersPerSites hint="list:AddIdentityProvidersPerSites">
                <mapEntry name="sites with extranet domain" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Collections.IdentityProvidersPerSitesMapEntry, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true" patch:instead="*[@name='sites with extranet domain']">
                    <sites hint="list">
                        <site>demo</site>
                    </sites>
                    <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
                        <identityProvider ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='DemoIdentityProvider']" />
                    </identityProviders>
                    <externalUserBuilder type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultExternalUserBuilder, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
                        <IsPersistentUser>false</IsPersistentUser>
                    </externalUserBuilder>
                </mapEntry>
            </identityProvidersPerSites>
            <identityProviders>
                <identityProvider id="DemoIdentityProvider" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
                    <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
                    <param desc="domainManager" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseDomainManager" resolve="true" />
                    <caption>Go to login</caption>
                    <domain>extranet</domain>
                    <triggerExternalSignOut>true</triggerExternalSignOut>
                    <!--list of identity transfromations which are applied to the provider when a user signin-->
                    <transformations hint="list:AddTransformation">
                        <!--SetIdpClaim transformation-->
                        <transformation name="Idp Claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.SetIdpClaimTransform, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" />
                        <!-- If external authentication is configured with "TokenValidationParameters = {SaveSigninToken = true}", this saves the value from "claimsIdentity.BootstrapContext" to the "id_token" claim. -->
                        <transformation name="set id_token claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.SaveIdTokenInClaim, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" />
                    </transformations>
                </identityProvider>
            </identityProviders>
        </federatedAuthentication>
        <pipelines>
            <owin.identityProviders>
                <processor type="demo.Foundation.SSO.IdentityProvider.DemoIdentityProvider, demo.Foundation.SSO" resolve="true" id="DemoIdentityProvider">
                    <scopes hint="list">
                        <scope name="openid">openid</scope>
                        <scope name="profile">profile</scope>
                        <scope name="offline_access">offline_access</scope>
                    </scopes>
                </processor>
            </owin.identityProviders>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**Scenario 1:**

- I have created blank login component
- Added `loginPage` and `requireLogin` in Site Grouping.

[image]

- Selected login page in Site grouping. If I don't select login page then it throw error `No login page specified for current site: demo (method: System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthenticationFiltersChallenge(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, ActionResult result)).`

[image]

Now while I am checking `www.demo.com/login` nothing is happening

**Scenario 2:**

- On login component I did below code:

```
 public override ActionResult Index()
        {
            var args = new GetSignInUrlInfoArgs("demo", "/");
            GetSignInUrlInfoPipeline.Run(_pipelineManager, args);
            model.Result = args.Result;
            return View(model);
        }
```

```
<div>
    @foreach (var signIn in Model.Result)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { @action = signIn.Href }))
        {
            <button type="submit">
                <img src="@signIn.Icon" />
                Login
            </button>
        }
    }
</div>
```

- On login button click, below requests are going

[image]

- It is redirecting to `https://xxx-sso-dev.sharepointguild.com/Oops/Error?statusCode=403`
- If I run get request in browser then it redirect to SSO and SSO is working but not on click of login button.
  [image]

I am really not sure in scenario 1 and scenario 2 what is wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to navigate to a protected page. If you do that Sitecore should redirect you to the Identity Provider if you are not logged in.

If you link to a protected page with the general link type this won't work by default. Because an anonymous user doesn't have access to the protected page it won't return the URL.

In order to get the URL of a protected page you need to use the `SecurityDisabler`.

For example this:

```
using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
{
    // TODO get the protected page from the general link item
}
```